# How to record microphone to MP3 with Delphi 10.4.2 on FMX Windows?

Tags: delphi, mp3, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

In FMX Delphi 10.4.2 I'm recording audio with this code:

```
  var
        fMicrophone: TAudioCaptureDevice;
begin

  fMicrophone := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;

  if fMicrophone = nil
    then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Audio capturing device not available');
        Exit;
      end;

  MicFilterStringLabel.Text := fMicrophone.FilterString;  // filter is *.wav

  RecordButton.Enabled := False;
  StopButton.Enabled := True;

      // Sets the name of the file to save the recorded data
  fMicrophone.FileName := TPath.Combine(gPreferences.TemporaryFolder, 'samplefile.mp3');

  fMicrophone.StartCapture;
end;

    // later the stop button calls fMicrophone.StopCapture;
```

This does not seem to create an authentic MP3 file. Perhaps it's still making a WAV file but just with the MP3 extension.

Can this component make an MP3 file?
Failing that, is there a component that will make MP3 files? (The mitov components don't seem to install on Delphi 10.4.2 and I don't have an email answer back from him about that yet.)

Comment: If you open the file in a hex editor it will become evident if it is a WAV or an MP3 file.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand ...or a WAV container with MP3 compression. I still have such files. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation (see [Audio-Video in FireMonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Audio-Video_in_FireMonkey) and [Audio Recording](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Audio_Recording)), the supported capture formats are:

- WAV on Windows
- CAF on iOS and Mac
- 3GP on Android

On Windows, `TAudioCaptureDevice` uses DirectShow, which does not support *capturing* MP3, only *playing* it.

So, if you want to record an MP3 file, you will have to convert the WAV file after recording it.  There are plenty of 3rd party libraries you can use for that.  Otherwise, you will have to capture and save the microphone audio yourself, such as by using platform APIs directly instead of using FireMonkey.

Comment: Just being curious, do you know if Media Foundation supports this? *Update:* [Seems like it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supported-media-formats-in-media-foundation)

Comment: Yes, [Media Foundation supports MP3 encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mp3-audio-encoder).

Comment: Apparently only on Windows 8 and later, though.

Comment: I am having trouble finding a 3rd party library that works. I just tried BASS which has three demo projects as tutorials. The first demo requires a DLL which will not work with my project. The second and third demos crash when converting from WAV to MP3.

Comment: Then feel free to post separate questions about those issues.

Answer (score 1):

[MfPack][1]contains the whole media foundation api and supports mp3 and mp4.
[1]: https://github.com/FactoryXCode/MfPack