# Which audio file format can be recorded and played back by FMX Delphi apps on Win, Mac, iOS, and Android?

Tags: delphi, audio, delphi-10.4-sydney

My Delphi 10-4-2 project must store audio snippets in a database. The databases are edited by the app on Windows, Macintosh, iOS, and Android.

What common audio format can be recorded by a Firemonkey app on all four of those platforms? And played back by the same app on all four platforms?

Comment: As I mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66823669/), FMX does not support a single common format across the various platforms for **recording** audio.

Comment: This question was already answered by @Remy in the link he provided. I just read it, and his answer there was very specific, and clearly indicates that there is NO common audio file format available for all platforms. Did you read that answer/

Comment: I will have to find a way for my app to record and play audio from the microphone and store it in documents which are used by all four platforms. That means those documents will use a common format or the app will have a way to convert to/from a common format for the outlying platforms using other formats.

As all four platforms seem to play MP3 audio using the stock FMX component, I'm going to keep looking for the final pieces to this puzzle. Perhaps someone knows how to get beyond the documented limitations.

Comment: @MikeatBookup If you found the solution then please post it as answer. I have my doubts that there is a cheat code available that just isn't documented, but would rather accept that what you want is just not possible. Of course, you could "just" compile/use/deploy another software, such as [LAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAME).

Comment: When i figure out a solution I will definitely add it here.

I'm envious of any coder who uses the word "just" when referring to compiling/using/deploying LAME. I'm still trying to figure out how to use it. In the past I've used Mitov's AudioLab components but they are apparently a no-go for Delphi 10.4.2.